# slicing a python list based on empty strings

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of this form:list

```
element11
element12
element13

element21
element23

element31
element32
element33
element34...
```

and so on. There is a blank string that occurs after a few elements (the number of elements is variable). I would like to split this list every time a blank string occurs and store it as a list of lists.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this. Just give it a key that describes where the breaks are and filter out the false values:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ["element11","element12","element13","","element21","element23","","element31","element32","element33","element34"]
list_of_lists = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, key=lambda s: s!="") if k]
```

**result - list_of_lists:**

```
[['element11', 'element12', 'element13'],
 ['element21', 'element23'],
 ['element31', 'element32', 'element33', 'element34']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by a simple for loop that checks for empty strings and saves the position of the last empty string. 
I call the .append again after the loop to catch the last slice

```
l = ['element11','element12','element13','','element21','element23','','element31','element32','element33']
l_new = []

start_i = 0


for i in range(len(l)):

    if (l[i]==''):

        l_new.append(l[start_i:i])
        start_i = i+1

l_new.append(l[start_i:i+1])

print(l_new)
```

which yields

```
[['element11', 'element12', 'element13'], ['element21', 'element23'], ['element31', 'element32', 'element33']]
```